# Несколько ссылок в HTML-баннере

Tags: javascript

Я не очень знаю js поэтому мне [не понятен пример](http://www.adriver.ru/doc/ban/spec/spec_624.html). Нужно ли прописывать в "a" ссылку или она будет сама подстраиваться из системы?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Vedomosti.Ru</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="/html.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function redirect(link, target){
                // Если вы не определили, в каком окне открывать форму, то возьмём этот параметр из AdRiver
                if (typeof(target) == 'undefined') target = ar_target;
                // Сформируем адрес для перехода
                var CgiHref = ar_redirect;
                // Добавляем закодированный адрес перехода
                if (link) CgiHref += escape(link);
                // Осуществляем переход
                switch (target){
                        case '_top':   window.top.location = CgiHref; break;   // Откроем в том же окне, если target=_top
                        case '_blank': window.open(CgiHref); break;        // Откроем в новом окне, если target=_blank.
                        case '_self':  document.location = CgiHref; break; // Откроем прямо в iframe баннера.
                        default: window.open(CgiHref); // По-умолчанию AdRiver откроет в новом окне.
                    }
                }
        </script>
        <a href="javascript:redirect('http://ru.stackoverflow.com', '_blank')" class="banner">
            <img class="button" src="button.png" width="188" height="88px">
            <img class="large-text" src="large-text.png" width="510" height="88px">
            <img class="small-text" src="small-text.png" width="397" height="88px">
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если атрибут `href` тега `a` начинается с `javascript:`, то при нажатии на ссылку будет исполнен js, прописанный после `javascript:`, т.е. в данном случае - `redirect('http://ru.stackoverflow.com', '_blank')`. Т.е. откроется новая вкладка с адресом `http://ru.stackoverflow.com`.

Для таких целей лучше использовать `<a href="ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">link</a>`. Произойдет то же самое, за тем исключением, что работает при отключенном js (это в случае с `"_blank"`). **Учитывая, что это, оказывается, сделано для рекламной системы, не стоит использовать href + target. Лучше сделать, как описано в документации.**

Если Вы не пропишите ссылку, то аргумент будет `undefined` сооветственно при попытке редиректа, подставится `undefined`, и адрес откроет страничку с адресом `'undefined'`, а такого адреса не существует.

---

В документации по ссылке - используется не один тэг `<a/>`, а несколько разных в одном банере:

```
<p><a href="javascript:redirect('http://www.adriver.ru', '_top')">Переход на сайт AdRiver</a>.
<p><a href="javascript:redirect('http://www.soloway.ru', '_blank')">Переход на сайт SoloWay</a>.
<p><a href="javascript:redirect('http://www.rle.ru', '_self')">Переход на сайт RLE</a>.
<p><a href="javascript:redirect('http://www.adgravity.ru/')">Переход на сайт AdGravity</a>.
```

`redirect('http://www.soloway.ru', '_blank')` в атрибуте href, есть ни что иное, как вызов js функции с передачей ей 2х аргументов, первый - `'http://www.soloway.ru'`, второй `'_blank'`, соответственно, внутри функции `redirect`, аргумент `link` будет равен `'http://www.soloway.ru'`, а аргумент `target` будет равен `'_blank'`. Т.е. изнутри функции он будет доступен. Если же нужно что-то еще - самый простой способ - из ссылки вызывать свой js, с которого передавать управление на функцию `redirect`, после всех желаемых манипуляций.

И да, указывать ссылку обязательно, иначе пользователя не вернет, куда нужно.

Comment: Как же тогда получить тот url, который был указан в поле Линк баннера? http://www.adriver.ru/doc/ban/spec/spec_576.html#3